# Create an ID based on integer with letter

Tags: php, mysql, identifier

I have a database containing messages with an `"id"` column in integer auto increment. Classical. But I would like to create a "visual" id based on this integer id. This is what I want :

```
A0001
A0002
[...]
A9999
B0001
B0002
[etc]
```

The ideal would be to generate automatically (in MYSQL) this messageId based on the integer id. I can also generate this id in PHP. But how ? The difficulty is that we have to check the last id in database to calculate what letter prefix the visual id.

Can you help me to generate this ? In MYSQL if it possible directly or in PHP?

Comment: You should do this with PHP, have you tried anything? To help: try to determine the letter first (based

Comment: what you have tried ??

Comment: Yes I try in PHP. I try to do a loop until 9999 and check what letter is appropriate but didn't work. I can't add "000" if integer is 1. And i can't know when to go on the next letter (after 9999 but how to differ the 9999 of letter A, and letter B, etc ?) I'm totally lost...

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following, but it is only good for numbers from 0 to 249999 (A0000 - Z9999)

```
select concat(char(ord('A')+round(ID / 10000)),ID % 10000) from ...
```

To convert back from a visual ID you can use the following:

```
select ord(VISUAL_ID)-ord('A')+mid(VISUAL_ID,2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! So if I want to add this visual ID on a field in my table I can do this : INSERT INTO messages (messageId) VALUES(concat(char(ord('A')+round(ID / 10000)),ID % 10000)); ?

Comment: Yes - obviously replacing ID with whatever the ID number is.

Comment: Thanks ! Very good pist. I just have a problem. I would like to have "A0001" if the id is 1. But I have A1. How to add corresponding 0 ?

Comment: You can use lpad(round(ID/10000),4,'0') instead of round(ID/10000)

Answer (score 0):

have you considered using hex? Why not to write `OxA001` it's still integer if you do `A001` then it's string and no AUTO INCREMENT is possible.

But if you want really to do it in mysql the only way would be using **TRIGGERS.**

You have 2 options you can create insert **AFTER** or **BEFORE** Insert statement and in this trigger you should update the value of ID to your value based on previous row. But I really recomend using **hex**.

You can read more about triggers [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can create such ids using a `before insert` trigger to create the new value.

Basically you would look up the maximum value and then increment it, by doing something like:

```
(case when maxvalue like '%9999'
      then concat(char(ascii(left(maxvalue, 1) + 1)), '0000')
      else concat(left(maxvalue, 1), lpad(right(maxvalue, 4) + 1), 4, '0')
 end);
```

However, I would discourage you from doing this and just set up a regular auto-increment column.

Answer (score 0):

try this it may help you.

```
for ($i = 'A'; $i != 'AA'; $i++) 
{
$prefix = $i;
$id = $prefix.sprintf("%03s",$suffix);
for ($j=1;$j<=5;$j++) 
{

$res = "$id"."$j";
echo "$res"."<br>";

}
}
```